# Sort Taxonomy List by Custom Values

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I'm trying to make the order of taxonomies adjustable. I've already got the drag & drop working and can put those values to the database.

I just don't know how to sort the taxonomy list by other values. The only thing I do is `register_taxonomy()` with `'show_admin_column' => true`.

There probably is some filter I can add to change the sorting, I just don't know how. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: What values are you putting to the database and how?

Comment: @David Well that doesn't really matter. I need to know how to sort the taxonomy list. Right now I'm putting the order in the options: `update_option( 'category_' . $t_id, $term_meta );`

Comment: It does matter, as it points out that you want to sort the terms by id.

Comment: @David No, I want to sort the terms by order. The order is saved in the database. But if I know how to sort the taxonomy list, I can always change the way it is saved so it works for the sorting of the taxonomy list. I just used this to have something in the database. I can change it to the format which is the best for sorting the taxonomy list.

Comment: Just to get this clear, when you talking about the »taxonomy list« you mean the screen WordPress serves at `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy={$taxonomy}`, right?

Comment: @David Yeah, but at my url it also says post_type. It is the screen wordpress automatically generates when you register a taxonomy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27186/discussion-between-kevin-van-mierlo-and-david).